# How to use iCloud as a stacks folder?

Tags: icloud, finder, dock

I'd like to know if anyone knows a backdoor way to use the iCloud drive as a stacks folder in the dock? Like shown in this picture: [image]

Apple advisor told me that it's not possible. Another Apple advisor had me create a copy of the iCloud folder on my desktop and drag that folder to the dock to use. I know that option won't work. The point is, he thought it was possible. So I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Comment: That's the accepted way to add a folder to the dock. Have you tried it?

Comment: I've tried dragging it to the dock... Not allowed to. If I drag it to the desktop first, it creates a copy of my iCloud Drive (not the synced original).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may achieve what you're looking for: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6605847?answerId=26864942022#26864942022

Copy and paste from the above link:

> It's pretty much impossible to get the complete iCloud Drive folder in
>   your dock. I did, however, find out how to add just the folders from
>   iCloud drive that I manually added. It's a bit of a workaround, but
>   this is how I did it.
>   - In finder you have to use go to folder (CMD+SHIFT+G) and navigate to ~/Library/
>   - Scroll down to Mobile Documents (This folders seems empty, but actually all your iCloud folders are hidden here)
>   - Drag Mobile Documents to your dock (Once added to your dock you can see it's contents).
>   - Look for the iCloud Drive folder via your new dock folder and drag this one to your dock again (yes it's possible to drag a subfolder,
>   opened via dock, back to your dock)
>   - Now you have a Folder called iCloud Drive in your dock. Remember this only contains the folders you manually added to iCloud drive, it
>   doesn't show the standard folders. So this solution might not be
>   good/work for everyone.
>
> As far as I understand, it's not possible to add your complete iCloud
>   drive folder to your dock. The reason for this is that it's contents
>   are actually fragmented in the ~/Library/Mobile Documents/ folder.
>
> Ow and don't play around (e.g. delete) any of the folders you find
>   under Mobile Documents. This will damage your iCloud Drive
>   functionality. That's a situation you don't want!

Comment: Brilliant. It worked like a charm. I'm not concerned with those automatically created folders anyways. This solution works for me. Thank you pdd!